# Symmetry in a $p$-sphere

Tags: geometry, symmetry

Let $S(p)$ be the unit sphere at the origin in the $\mathcal{l}_p$-norm. What symmetries does it have? For instance in the $\mathcal{l}_2$-norm we have unitary symmetry in the Euclidean case. In general for $\mathcal{l}_p$-norm what can we expect for Euclidean, Elliptic and Hyperbolic spaces?

Comment: The unit sphere in what space?

Comment: Can we have $\mathcal{l}_p$-norm in non-archimedean space?

Comment: What do you mean by Elliptic and Hyperbolic spaces? By Euclidean spaces, do you mean $\mathbb R^n$? To answer your question: it depends on what you mean by $l_p$ norm.

Comment: I am thinking something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions.

Comment: The pictures in the article are representative of the general case and answer your question!

Comment: no they dont for $p=p$

Comment: For $p=p$??? $\textbf{}$

Comment: The pictures are correct: When $p\neq 2$ and you're in $\mathbb R^2$, the unit ball in the $l_p$ norm has the same symmetry group as the square.